# Linq to EF : Confusion of returning IQueryable object

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I understand that if I call the code below, will query data from the database and return the actual object in locally in memory. After calling this code, the later manipulation of the list will not calling to the database again:

```
db.Context.Where(...).ToList()
```

If I don't use ToList with only Where or with Select call, it will return a IQueryable<> object.

```
var data = db.Context.Where(...).Select (...) or db.Context.Where(...);
```

Does that mean, the method not yet call database to fetch the data, until I call ToList, First() etc...

```
foreach (var a in data) 
{
   var b = a.SomeCollection.ToList() 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create and manipulate your Query as you needed using IQuery<> interface.

if you see it's properties, you will find that, it's all about handling SQL queries. it has a `Provider`, `Query`, `ConnectionString` and etc... .

Actually, when you call `ToList<>` or `ToArray<>` or something like it, it just commands to IQueryable Object to execute it's SQL Query against DataBase.

Comment: In the edited code, the a.SomeCollection.ToList() will it call the database each time it iterate.

Comment: yes of course, if SomeCollection is an entity (something like a join), your code will fetch SomeCollction for all of its members at each iteration. so you have a new List of items at each iteration.

Comment: what about the 'a' itself in the for loop, will it be called to the database to fetch one of 'a' when looping through

Comment: in your codes, `foreach` will gets `data`'s collection. as like as we say `data.ToList`. so we have a Query execution at the beginning of the `foreach`. and then for each element (we call them `a` in your sample) we have another calls. so we have `1+(Number of elements in data's collection)` Query execution against database.